# Calculation using java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have one  List, want to write a  stream based code to find the average price.

1. Input parameter is a list of PT class with Qty and Price fields.

Input:

```
[PT(qty=300, price=57.8),           
PT(qty=200, price=57.5),        
PT(qty=240, price=57.2)]
```

Output:

```
Price = (300 x 57.86 +200 x 57.5 + 240 x 57.28) / 740 = 57.57
```

PT class:

```
class PT{       
   BigDecimal price;      
   BigDecimal qty;  
}
```

I am bit confused how to write one function that produce the above mentioned output. 
It will be a great help if somebody can throw some light. Thanks

Comment: You can't do it manually in a one-way Stream, as you can't manage the sum of produts AND the total sum in one way, use the given duplicate link, or usr a for-each loop

Comment: there's an answer with extensive explanation here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635945/adding-up-bigdecimals-using-streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635945/adding-up-bigdecimals-using-streams)

Comment: @Naman I don't think you dupe target will be sufficient for OP, as they needs to use weighted average. It is probably easier to convert [Calculate weighted average with Java 8 streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40420823/525036) to use `BigDecimal` instead of `double`/`long`.

Comment: @azro You _can_ actually do it in a one-way stream, by using a custom collector.

Answer (score 0):

As you have 2 parameters in you class, you can't use the classic [`BigDecimal summary statistics`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51645432/bigdecimal-summary-statistics)

You may use a loop:

```
List<PT> list = new ArrayList<>() {{
    add(new PT(57.8, 300));
    add(new PT(57.5, 200));
    add(new PT(57.2, 240));
}};

BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO, product = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for (PT p : list) {
    sum = sum.add(p.getQty());
    product = product.add(p.getQty().multiply(p.getPrice()));
}
double result = product.divide(sum, RoundingMode.CEILING).doubleValue();
System.out.println(result);
```

---

If your values are not so big, and can fit in a double `max 1.7976931348623157e+308` , use it it'll cost you less